# Entity Framework Code First - Entity maps to one or the other

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I have Entity1 and Entity2 for example:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public int Entity1ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public int Entity2ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to add comments that are associated with each entity. This is easy enough if you were to have `class Entity1_Comments` and `Entity2_Comments` for example. Is there a way to store all the comments in one table though without confusion as to whether the record is mapping to an Entity1 record or Entity2 record?

You could for instance structure the comments table such that it has:

```
CommentID
Entity1_or_Entity2
ForeignKeyID
...
```

as the table columns. Thereby checking which record type the comments is associated with using the column Entity1_or_Entity2 and then using the ForeignKeyID to find that record. I'm not sure how you might go about this using code-first though.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to set up TPH (table per hierarchy) inheritance on the Comment entity.  That is, make a Comment base class, make Comment1 a derived class with FK to Entity1, and Comment2 a derived class with FK to entity 2. You end up with extra columns in your Comment table (two FKs instead of 1, plus a discriminator).  See
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the job. So using the new setup where the shared columns are in an abstract class 'comment', it generates one table comments with a column Entity1ID and Entity2ID. All good. The two Entity classes have a shared column 'user', so in the abstract class there is `public virtual User user { get; set; }`. In the generated table there are three columns User_UserID, User_UserID1 and User_UserID2 and all three are foreign keys. Surely it only need generate one UserID column so why generate three?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code, but it could be a bug in Code First.  The EF team monitors the EF forum and you might try posting a question there.  As a workaround you might be able to cut the number of FKs down from 3 to 2 by moving the User property to the derived classes.  The EF forum is at social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework does not support heterogeneous associations. Other frameworks handle this automatically (NHibernate, for example, provides the `any` mapping).

My solution is to mimic what NHibernate does, but manually.

There's a `Comment` entity with `EntityType` and `EntityID` fields, no foreign keys. A `NoteService` allows me to add/retrieve notes from any entity by storing/querying using those fields.

The only thing you will not have, of course, is direct navigation.